# Converting List to JSON array in Python

Tags: python, json

I have a list of items which I grabbed from a table on some website and I converted this into JSON. My approach is:

```
r = requests.get("some_url")
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
data = []

names = soup.find_all("keyword")
for name in names:
    data.append(name.text)

table = soup.find_all("td")
for item in table:
    item_text = item.text.strip()
    data.append(item_text)

with io.open('data.json', 'w', encoding='utf8') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile, ensure_ascii=False)
```

this gave me the output like this:

```
["name",
    "component1",
    "unit value",
    "x",
    "y",
    "z",
    "component1",
    "unit value",
    "x2",
    "y2",
    "z2",
    "component2",
    "unit value",
    "x3",
    "y3",
    "z3",

    ...
```

I want to convert that into something like this:

```
{
    "table": {
        "id":"1",
        "title": "name",
        "component1": [
          {
            "unit":"unit value",
            "x value":"x",
            "y value":"y",
            "z value":"z"
          },
          {
            "unit":"unit value",
            "x value":"x",
            "y value":"y",
            "z value":"z"
          }
        ],
        "component2":[
          {
            "unit":"unit value",
            "x value":"x",
            "y value":"y",
            "z value":"z"
          }
        ]

        ...

    }
}
```

How can I format my JSON output like this?

The html file:

```
  <table id="table">
    <tr>
      <th>component</th>
      <th>unit</th>
      <th>x value</th>
      <th>y value</th>
      <th>z value</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td ><a href="#">
component1

</a>&nbsp;</td>
     <td class="right ">unit</td>
     <td class="right "><nobr>x&nbsp;</nobr></td>
     <td class="right "><nobr>y&nbsp;</nobr></td>
     <td class="right "><nobr>z&nbsp;</nobr></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="alt"><a href="/#">
component1

</a>&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="right alt">unit</td>
      <td class="right alt"><nobr>x2&nbsp;</nobr></td>
      <td class="right alt"><nobr>y2&nbsp;</nobr></td>
      <td class="right alt"><nobr>z2&nbsp;</nobr></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td ><a href="#">
component2

</a>&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="right ">unit</td>
      <td class="right "><nobr>x3&nbsp;</nobr></td>
      <td class="right "><nobr>y3&nbsp;</nobr></td>
      <td class="right "><nobr>z3&nbsp;</nobr></td>
     </tr>
    ...
```

Comment: Forget the JSON... How would you build a Python dictionary like that? All you have are lists

Comment: @cricket_007 so you are saying that there is no way to create this kind of data structure?

Comment: @Spootrick you are lossing information when you are converting your html table into list. Don't loose that information, Utilize that to build the dictionary. If you can share the html table we might be able to help you.

Comment: That's not what I said at all... You are appending to a single, flat list. You need `dict`objects if you want "nested structure".

Comment: My point is that once you have a Python dictionary, the JSON dumps command is going to give the output you want, so JSON is not the issue here - it's your parsing logic

Comment: @VikashSingh sure I can share

Comment: @cricket_007 I get it but I couldn't do it with dictionary i'm kinda new in python so I decided to do it in this way

Comment: That's fine and all, but I'm telling you what the solution is... It's hard to help more than that without access to the HTML source

Comment: @Spootrick then please share the html/ table. or share the url if its public link.

Comment: Pointers: you need a list for each unique component name. Try getting that started. Between each component, you have one or more units, so you need logic to determine where those start and end within the  table. You probably can't just loop over all the `td` elements and expect to get that

Comment: @Spootrick I added a solution. Hope its good enough. Let me know if you need any changes to the structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment

t = """<html><table id="table">
    <tr>
      <th>component</th>
      <th>unit</th>
      <th>x value</th>
      <th>y value</th>
      <th>z value</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td ><a href="#">
component1

</a>&nbsp;</td>
     <td class="right ">unit</td>
     <td class="right "><nobr>x&nbsp;</nobr></td>
     <td class="right "><nobr>y&nbsp;</nobr></td>
     <td class="right "><nobr>z&nbsp;</nobr></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="alt"><a href="/#">
component1

</a>&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="right alt">unit</td>
      <td class="right alt"><nobr>x2&nbsp;</nobr></td>
      <td class="right alt"><nobr>y2&nbsp;</nobr></td>
      <td class="right alt"><nobr>z2&nbsp;</nobr></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td ><a href="#">
component2

</a>&nbsp;</td>
      <td class="right ">g</td>
      <td class="right "><nobr>x3&nbsp;</nobr></td>
      <td class="right "><nobr>y3&nbsp;</nobr></td>
      <td class="right "><nobr>z3&nbsp;</nobr></td>
     </tr></<table></html>"""

bs = BeautifulSoup(t)

results = {}
for row in bs.findAll('tr'):
    # build the header
    aux = row.findAll('th')
    if aux:
        keys = [val.text.strip() for val in aux]
        continue
    # for rows other than header
    aux = row.findAll('td')
    if aux:
        # for each row build the dictionary equivalent
        temp_res = {}
        for idx, key in enumerate(keys):
            if key == 'component':
                component_name = aux[idx].text.strip()
            temp_res[key] = aux[idx].text.strip()

    # append the component value to result
    if component_name in results:
        results[component_name].append(temp_res)
    else:
        results[component_name] = [temp_res]

# adjusting the result in the format you requested. adding id/title.
import json
results["id"] = "1"
results["title"] = "name"

main_result = {"table": results}

json.dumps(main_result)
```

output:

```
{
    "table": {
        "component2": [
            {
                "component": "component2",
                "z value": "z3",
                "unit": "g",
                "x value": "x3",
                "y value": "y3"
            }
        ],
        "id": "1",
        "component1": [
            {
                "component": "component1",
                "z value": "z",
                "unit": "unit",
                "x value": "x",
                "y value": "y"
            },
            {
                "component": "component1",
                "z value": "z2",
                "unit": "unit",
                "x value": "x2",
                "y value": "y2"
            }
        ],
        "title": "name"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time this is exactly what I want.

Comment: @Spootrick : you are welcome. Someone still down voted it, but thanks for accepting :)